# How to rewrite field in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I tried to rewrite a primary key in laravel like as:

```
public function setIdAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['id'] = $value; // or instead $value $this->attributes['idCity']
    }
```

So I need to replace value of `id` field on value of `idCity` field

Comment: Can you be clear enough with your question? What are you trying to achieve here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename a columns you should create a new migration
To create migration for this change write on console

```
php artisan make:migration swapKeyId
```

then go to database->migrations->...swapkey....php
in method called **function up()** write the code below but replace your table name in my case i use users

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->renameColumn('id', 'userId');
});
```

now its time to push migrates to database

```
php artisan migrate
```

and its done. this method is renamin it via laravel, also you can change it directly to the database(MySQL,MariaDB,SQL Server etc)

Answer (score 0):

Setting an attribute in your model to define how php should store a value is something entirely different from creating a primary key in MySQL. Setup your migrations following the documentation and there isn't a lot that can go wrong:

[Migrations in Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations)